# Concurrency - how to assign variable from separate task?

Tags: concurrency

Consider the following scenario:

```
    |---------------------|------------------|
    |        Task 0       |       Task 1     |
    |---------------------|------------------|
    |        x = 1;       |       y = 1;     |
    |---------------------|------------------|
    |        a = y;       |       b = x;     |
    |---------------------|------------------|
```

What is the value of a and b at the end of the concurrent tasks? I have no idea how to approach this problem.

Each assignment executes atomically. Within tasks, the statements occur in order. Before execution, both x and y are set to 0.

Comment: Without synchronization, you can't say with certainty.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I updated the question with some more information in case it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't be certain of the values after both tasks have run even though the assignments are atomic. This is because you are still dealing with two tasks running concurrently and the values have a dependency on an interleaving of statements which can't be guaranteed. But you can certainly produce a set of possible value pairs.

For example, say Task 0 runs to completion before Task 1 is able to set y. We have `{a = 0, b = 1}`. The same can be said when Task 1 runs to completion before Task 0 is able to set x giving `{a = 0, b = 1}, {a = 1, b = 0}`. The simple example leaves only one other possibility since they both can't be 0 so the final set would be:

> [{a = 0, b = 1}, {a = 1, b = 0}, {a = 1, b = 1}]

---

> How to assign variable from separate task?

The easiest way to avoid concurrency issues is to not create them. Let the tasks return the values of x and y and isolate the mutations of a and b in sequential code. The tasks have a dependency on one another so why not pull that dependency out of the task where it's safe?